# mongodb PHP extension not found?

Tags: php, mongodb

I followed the manual, I mpved the php_mongo.dll into the PHP extension folder,
and added extension=php_mongo.dll to the php.ini file and it's given me an error when I try and you rockmango that "To make things right, you must install php_mongo module. Here for installation documents on PHP.net." but I have alread done this any solutions? I am running the lattest version of PHP and mongodb

Comment: correct I did, I am using a wamp installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `php --ini` shows the correct config file being used.

Check `php -i` (phpinfo) and make sure the module is **actually** loaded.

Double check you have the right flavour of the module for your version of PHP. (VC6, VC8, VC9, TS, NTS, etc.)

I got my mongo module (1.2.9) for PHP 5.4 32bit on windows from [stealth35](https://github.com/stealth35/stealth35.github.com/downloads). It works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you so much Leigh. The link to get dll file for php 5.4 is very helpful.

Comment: Also - if anyone else still has issues, check that your php-pear installer is up to date

Answer (score 0):

Often there are multiple PHP locations with different php.ini files.

If you are worried about working in mod_php (through apache) or as a fastcgi then create a file with the following contents.

`<?php phpinfo();`

Then visit that file in a browser. It will have all the settings and modules listed that are currently being loaded. It will also tell you which php.ini file and modules directory being used.

Please make sure that the ini listed is the one you added mongo dll line.